# F#: Passing a function to Option.bind

Tags: function, functional-programming, f#

I have a function `great` and it is implemented as below

```
let great y z = Option.bind (cons (Option.get z) >> Some) y
```

And I have the function apply as below

```
let apply f val = 
  match f with
  | None -> None
  | Some v -> Option.map v val
```

If I give the `None` value for the second parameter (`z`) it is giving me an error since Option.get z returns an error when it gets `None`.

I want to avoid this error without using if else blocks. I wonder is it possible to pass the `great` function to apply so that it can evaluate `None` when the given `z` parameter is `None`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot pass the great function to apply because the f argument signature have to be : ('a -> 'b) option and the great signature is: 'a list option -> 'a option -> 'a list option. Anyway, the apply function does not check if val is None.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute the whole `Option.bind ...` thing only when `z` is `Some`, you can just use another `Option.bind` for that - that's exactly what `bind` is for:

```
let great y maybeZ = 
    Option.bind (fun z -> Option.bind (cons z >> Some) y) maybeZ
```

Or, to express it more elegantly:

```
let great maybeY maybeZ = 
    maybeZ |> Option.bind (fun z -> 
    maybeY |> Option.bind (cons z >> Some) )
```

The first line would then read like "bind maybeZ to z, and..."

In fact, I would probably do the same thing with `y` just for extra readability:

```
let great maybeY maybeZ = 
    maybeZ |> Option.bind (fun z -> 
    maybeY |> Option.bind (fun y ->
    Some (z :: y) ) )
```

Alternatively, you can use `Option.map2`, which does exactly this: applies a function to two `option`-typed parameters when both are `Some`:

```
let great maybeY maybeZ = 
    Option.map2 (fun y z -> z :: y) maybeY maybeZ
```

And then you can eta-reduce it (but, sadly, only for `maybeZ`, due to the value restriction):

```
let great maybeY = 
    Option.map2 (fun y z -> z :: y) maybeY
```

Or you could get rid of the lambda instead if you just reversed the parameters:

```
let great maybeY maybeZ = 
    Option.map2 cons maybeZ maybeY
```

Comment: It still gives an error when I pass None as a parameter.

Comment: It cannot happen. Are you sure you're actually calling the new code? What's the error?

Comment: ˇWhen i call `great (Some[]) None` it says; Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type

Comment: This is a compile-time error, not runtime. Not related to the original error you were getting at all. This happens because the compiler doesn't know what type the result of that call should be. Should it be `int list option` or `string list option`? Or perhaps `bool list option`? The compiler has no way to know.

Comment: Got it, what am i supposed to do in that case ?

Comment: You need to provide the type in some way. Either with an explicit type annotation (e.g. `great (Some []) (None : int option)`) or by specifying some values from which the compiler can infer the types (e.g. `great (Some [1]) None`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the great function using pattern matching like the apply function.

```
let great lOpt xOpt = 
    match lOpt, xOpt with
    | Some l, Some x -> Some (x :: l)
    | Some l, None   -> Some l
    | _              -> None
```